# Cannot run the war generated from Gradle BootRepackage in a JHipster-based web Application

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm trying to run with `java -jar` the war file produce by `./gradlew -Pprod bootRepackage`. The `bootRepackage` task successful concludes.

When I look in the `project_root/build/libs/` folder, the war and war.original files are created with the following permissions:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 110376521 Apr 24 09:42 app-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 107542786 Apr 24 09:40 app-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war.original
```

In my build.gradle, I have the following:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

bootRepackage {
    mainClass = 'org.package.Application'
}

// Original from JHipster. Uncommenting this does not work either.
//springBoot {
//    mainClass = 'org.package.Application'
//}

// I got this from [this][1] questions, but did not work either.
war {
    baseName = 'app'
    version =  '0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.package.Application'
    }
}
```

When I run the jar I get:

```
$ java -jar app-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war --spring.profiles.active=prod
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No 'Start-Class' manifest entry specified in jar:file:/home/user/.../build/libs/app-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war!/
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.Archive.getMainClass(Archive.java:57)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.getMainClass(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:63)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:61)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:80)
```

What should I do? Thanks.

**Update**
I unziped the war and looked into the MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Start-Class: org.package.Application
Spring-Boot-Version: 1.1.7.RELEASE
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher
```

I this correct?

Comment: why is the manifest main-class set to Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher when your set it as attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.package.Application'???

Comment: @al-Jacinto It's strange, but reading more online I believe I have an explanation. It's because Spring Boot is the first class the JDK must run in order to get the application running. Spring boot has to run the web server, etc, etc... and then my own class. I just dont know why it is not founding the `Start-Class` in the jar.

Comment: Ok, didn't know this is spring boot.  You should change the Start-Class instead of the main-class because like you said, spring-boot will the one to start it.  This from the ref doc I believe (can't remember where I got it):You need to specify an appropriate Launcher as the Main-Class attribute of META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. The actual class that you want to launch (i.e. the class that you wrote that contains a main method) should be specified in the Start-Class attribute.
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher
Start-Class: com.mycompany.project.MyApplication

Comment: Looking at your error, that is what exactly it says :)  And the manifest has a default value for Start-Class attribute.

Comment: I know, but the Start-Class is correct in the MANIFEST.MF! That is the point.

Comment: Got it.  I can replicate your issue.  And it works if you get rid of the bootRepackage statement.  Comparing the MANIFEST generated, it looks like the one that works (without the bootRepackage) has Start-Class:  Application -- without package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the build.gradle that works, bootRepackage commented out:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
                        }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.3.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
}

//bootRepackage {
//    mainClass = 'org.package.Application'
//    }

war {
    baseName = 'app'
    version =  '0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.package.Application'
    }
}
```

Diff in the MANIFEST.INF

```
> libs  diff META-INF/MANIFEST.MF ~/temp/MANIFEST-MF-works 
2c2
< Start-Class: org.package.Application
---
> Start-Class: Application
```

in action

```
> sample        /opt/java/bin/java -jar build/libs/app-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.3.RELEASE)

2015-04-24 18:44:55.443  INFO 18776 --- [           main] Application                              : Starting Application on vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 with PID 18776 (started by developer in /home/developer/developments/gradle-sandbox/sample)
```

Comment: getting rid of the package also works mainClass = 'Application'

Comment: Can you check this with Spring Boot 1.1.7? I commented out the bootRepackage and set the manifest attributes as `org.package.Application` and also as only `Application`, but still get the same error. I will try here also.

Comment: Works for that version as well `:: Spring Boot ::        (v1.1.7.RELEASE)
`

Comment: I run your mini example and was able to java -jar the war generated also. But in my complete gradle.build application it did not worked. I will generate a full jHipster application tomorrow and see if it runs normally the war.

Comment: I thinking my issue has something to do with the zip64 property I'm using inside the `war{ }`. When I create a new application, I can run the war generated perfectly fine. However, as I start adding the dependencies (and the code) I need, at some point it cannot found the start class.

Comment: I'm afraid the problem may be the Zip64. Check this: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gralde-2-3-bootrepackage-with-zip64-true-cannot-find-start-class/9372