# Gradle 2.3 - BootRepackage with Zip64=true cannot find Start-Class

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

(I posted this initially in the [Gradle Forum](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-2-3-bootrepackage-with-zip64-true-cannot-find-start-class/9372), but I'm reproducing it here because I think SO has much more visibility).

I wasn't able to execute the **war** generated from **bootRepackage** in a project derived from jHipster framework. The topic still opened in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29848088/cannot-run-the-war-generated-from-gradle-bootrepackage-in-a-jhipster-based-web-a).

I created a small application and put it on [Github](https://github.com/pmdusso/boot-repackage-test) to help you help me with this. Following these steps I believe you can reproduce the problem also. I'm first packing a simple Spring application and then running the generated war. This will create 66000 files in the resource folder. Packing the same app again will fail because in the second time there is more than 65535 files. We confirmed this by cleaning the resource folder and bootRepackaging it again successfully.

Then I set the **zip64** property to **true** (I had to do it in the *jar { }* task also. In my original application however I do not have a jar task and set only in the war task). The bootRepackage task completes with success, but then when I run the war I get the **no Start-Class error**.

Running this for the first time will work, because total files < 65535 and zip64 = false

> ./gradlew clean bootRepackage; java -jar build/libs/app-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

Running this for the second time will not work, because total files > 65535 and zip64 = false

> ./gradlew clean bootRepackage; java -jar build/libs/app-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

Running this for the third time (equal to alternative one) will work, because total files < 65535 and zip64 = false

> rm src/main/resources/*; ./gradlew clean bootRepackage; java -jar build/libs/app-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

At this point we have total files > 65535 and zip64 = false. We change zip64 property to true and try to bootPackage it again

> Set zip64 = true in build.gradle in jar and war tasks.
>   ./gradlew clean bootRepackage; java -jar build/libs/app-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No 'Start-Class' manifest entry specified in jar:file:../boot-repackage-test/build/libs/app-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war!/
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.Archive.getMainClass(Archive.java:57)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.getMainClass(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:69)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:61)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:61)
```

To conclude, `unzip app-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war && cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` yields:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Start-Class: org.Application
Spring-Boot-Version: 1.2.3.RELEASE
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher
```

Best regards,

Pedro Dusso

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot executable JARs currently don't support the zip64 format. I would recommend trying to restructure your application so that assets are packaged into distinct nested JARs (regular zip format with <65535 files). Alternatively you could use the [Gradle shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) to repackage your app.